# Can we "wrap" templated classes with non-templated classes in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

*Disclaimer: I am afraid the short answer to my question is "not possible". But since I am not a C++ expert, I thought I still give it a try and ask here, maybe there is some kind of solution which I am just not aware of.*

So I have templated container-like class `MyContainer` that internally stores data in a `std::list<T>`, where `T` is the class template type. This works fine.

Now I want to add another class, which has to map instances of that templated container class in a `std::map<std::string, MyContainer>`. However, the compiler asks me to provide the template class type for the value-part of the map, as in `std::map<std::string, MyContainer<T>>`. But I would rather omit this template here, since that would in turn require me to use templates for the wrapper class as well.

Thus my question: Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do, omitting the template type for the wrapper class, at least to some extend? Or is this just not possible in C++, because the compiler needs that information in any case?

Comment: There is no such thing as "templated class". C++ has class templates. Class templates are not classes. Your description is far from clear. Please show more of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One common technique for doing this is inheritance.

You make `MyContainer<T>` inherit from some base class, such as `MyBaseContainer`. `MyBaseContainer` is not a template class, but `MyContainer` is. The `MyBaseContainer` class has virtual functions that the templated class overrides.

Then, you make your map of type `std::map<std::string, MyBaseContainer*>`. It will be able to call the virtual functions on the containers it stores, without having to know the template type of each one.

This is how `std::function` works.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: The only problem here is that MyBaseContainer cannot have too many useful virtual functions.

Comment: If you absolutely must, you can also use `dynamic_cast<MyContainer<xy> *>()` (or, in some cases, even `static_cast`) on `MyBaseContainer` pointers. However, that's a pretty ugly design.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but a bit tricky. If i understand you correctly you want each `MyContainer` class stored inside `map` to possibly have different template specialization (say some will hold `std::list<int>` while other will hold `std::list<string>`) then you value type for map can no longer be just `MyContainer` but rather class that could hold both `list<int>` and `list<string>`.

One way to do it to use inheritance as @IanPudney already pointed out.

However you can do this even without creating inheritance hierarchy for `MyContainer` classes if you instead declare map as `map<string, boost::any>` (see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) that way you will be able to store any kind of `MyContainer` inside this map without the need to create inheritance hierarchy in advance.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this idea. I would rather not use boost lib though (or any other third party lib).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to do this without using inheritance but this may also depend on a few deciding factors. The first question is: Upon creating an instance of the outside class is the type of the template container known. If it is then this is an easy class to write. If it is not then it can still be done but there would be more work involved. If case is not known there are 2 ways to do this and the first is the one you are trying to avoid by not making this a class template. The second involves more work which some of the logic on how to define this class will be shown.

**Pseudo Code:** -- 1st Case Where Type Is Known Upon Creation

```
#include <map> 

template<class T>
class MyContainer {
    // ... Class Variables, Constructors & Methods
}

// For Demonstration We will say that `T` is known to be an int upon instantiation
class MyClass {
private:
    std::map< std::string, MyContainer<int> > maps_;

public:
    MyClass() {}
    ~MyClass() {
        // Clear Out Map
    }

    void addItem( std::string& str, int value ) {
        maps_.insert( std::make_pair( str, MyContainer<int>( value ) ); 
    }        
};
```

Now for the 2nd case where the type is not known using the method without templating the wrapper you will need to know of all of the types that this class can support and you will need to create `typedef` of each of these.

**Pseudo Code** -- 2nd Case Where Type Is Not Known:

```
#include <map> 

template<class T>
class MyContainer {
    // ... Class Variables, Constructors & Methods
}

// For Demonstration We will say that `T` is unknown before instantiation
class MyClass {
public:
    typedef MyContainer<int> INTS;
    typedef MyContainer<float> FLOATS;
    typedef MyContainer<double> DOUBLES;
    // And Do This For Every Type This Class Will Support.

private:
    std::map< std::string, INTS >    mapInts_;
    std::map< std::string, FLOATS >  mapFloats_;
    std::map< std::string, DOUBLES > mapDoubles_;
    // And You Will Need A Container For Each Supporting Type
public:

    MyClass() {}
    // If You Have Constructors Other Than Default That Excepts Parameter Types
    // You Will Need A Constructor For Each Supporting Type

    ~MyClass() {
        // Clear Out All Maps
    }

    void addInts( std::string& str, MyClass::INTS );
    void addFloats( std::string& str, MyClass::FLOATS );
    void addDoubles( std::string& str, MyClass::DOUBLES );
    // And You Will Need A Corresponding Function For Each Type This Class Supports.

};
```